# Part Name Identification - PCB mounted wire clamp terminal

Tags: identification, wire, wire-terminals, screw-terminal

I have a wall outlet that i took apart, and there are mounted wire terminal blocks there. I tried searching for what kind they are, and couldn't find anything. There is a screw that tightens a paddle blade to a mounted wire terminal with a U shape for the screw.

What is the actual technical name of this type of wire terminal clamp?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The better kinds look like [this](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/terminal-blocks-wire-to-board/371); what you have is more of [this](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/terminals-screw-connectors/396?FV=-8%7C396&quantity=0&ColumnSort=-1000009&page=1&pageSize=25) nature.

Comment: @MarcusMüller i found the ones you mentioned. But not this one type.

Comment: it may be custom made ... it is basically a terminal block without the insulation .... found this ... https://ever-hardware.com/pcb-screws-custom-made-pcb-mounting.html